# css function imported from '@emotion/react' does not work with mui styled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

the css function imported from '@emotion/react' works in the case,

```
const Button = styled('button')`
  ${css`background-color: blue`}
`
```

but doesn't work in the case,

```
const Button = styled('button')(props => `
  ${css`background-color: blue`}
`);
```

Check the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-ully-upvzhz?file=/src/App.js) for complete example.

What is the difference between the above two methods? Why does it work in the first case but doesn't work in the second case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a prop they should be inside template literal, for example

```
const Button = styled('button')(props => `
  background-color: ${props => props.color};
`);
```

you don't need to use css function. Why it doesn't work, I assume styled expect a template literal instead of function and that's why.